# "Unable to acess page" error while creating a user in salesforce

Tags: user, error-messages

I am running into an error while trying to create a user. When I hit the Save button, an error is displayed as follows.

Unable to Access Page
"You are missing information needed by the page you have attempted to access. If you believe this is an error, please refresh your screen. If the error persists, please report it to our Customer Support team and provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information"

Please help me out if you have faced anything like this.
Thanks